# Azure SQL Data warehouse ADO.Net Error Codes

Tags: sql, azure, data-warehouse

I just want to ask the following questions below:

1. Are SQL error codes in Azure SQL database will also apply in Azure SQL Data Warehouse?
2. Can anyone point me the URL where I can find list of error codes that's specific only from Azure SQL data warehouse?

Cheers,
Jhessie

Comment: I've seen this already but the error codes specified here are for Azure SQL database not for Azure SQL data warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same. Reference: [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cbc5d83d-66d7-4e1c-a21f-9cc67cbe7ce4/transient-error-codes-of-azure-sql-data-warehouse?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse)

To view all the error messages, you can execute this query on master:

```
select * from sys.messages;
```